# Blackberry Application Development by integrating code generated from MBO's in Sybase Unwired Platform

Tags: blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am developing a simple Blackberry Application using Blackberry Plugins for Ecplise. I had created a MBO for Customer using the Customer table avaliable in the My Sample Database of Sybase Unwired Platform(version 1.5.2), and generated the codes for this MBO and added these Generated code to the src folder of my application in the Blackberry Plugin for Ecplise. Then added all the required .jar files and .cod files to the application. While running this application by choosing the Run as Blackberry Simulator, it is showing an error.

> Error starting SUP101Sample: Module 'sup$2dclient$2drim' not found

Can you please help me, how to correct this error, and run the application?

Answer (score 1):

Upgraded the Sybase Unwired Platform from 1.5.2 to 1.5.5.

Since I am using *Sybase Unwired Platform of version 1.5.5,* in order to access the code generated by this version I need to use Blackberry Plugin for Ecplise, which is having the *JRE 5.0.0*.

And in case of the `.cod` files we need to use `sup_client_rim.cod` and `UltraLiteJ.cod` for doing this.

This solves the problem.

Comment: Upgraded the Sybase Unwired Platform from 1.5.2 to 1.5.5